# D7 multi-role comment permission per content type - how-to?

Tags: 7, nodes, comments, users

I'd like to extend (...or create) a content type/node that allows:
commenting by two or more roles though one role's members can not see the other roles' comments/replies as well as one role that is granted permission to see all comments/replies for that content type/node.

Has anyone already solved this and what would they recommend as an approach to solve this requirement?